# Is there any way to trust "Untrusted Developer" enterprise app programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Is there any way to trust "Untrusted Developer"  enterprise app programmatically?

Comment: Nopes. That's exactly the point of disabling untrusted enterprise developer apps by default

Comment: Ideally enterprise apps should be installed by an MDM. In that case trust is established automatically https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204460

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it programatically. It is not possible you have to provide complete process to user's who are going to install enterprise application on their device . Like

In iOS 9.1 and lower, go to Settings - General - Profiles - tap on your Profile - tap on Trust button.

In iOS 9.2+, go to Settings - General - Device Management - tap on your Profile - tap on Trust button.