# IOS trust enterprise apps by certificate

Tags: ios, certificate, enterprise, trust

Is it possible to trust an enterprise application without going through all of the settings ? For example using a certificate or move client directly to wanted settings page. I download an app from the website. According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38865096/6612115 user has to trust it by himself but no one mention about certificates